# Convert NSData to float array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

What is the most efficient way to convert a NSData to a float array?

I've the following:

```
NSData* dataOutputNumDetections = [outputNumDetections dataWithError:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",dataOutputScore);
```

Resulting this:

```
 {length = 100, bytes = 0xf1699f3e cef5953e 32278d3e ae668b3e ... 6606483e 64ff463e }
```

`NSData dataOutputNumDetections` contains 25 float32 values. I would like to convert all the bytes values and store the result in a size 25 float array.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
float output[25];
[dataOutputScore getBytes:output length:(sizeof(float) * 25)];
```